# Reflection: Why does parent close when child is closed?

Tags: java, swing, reflection

I started playing around with Java Reflection and I am boggled as to why is my parent app closes when I close the child app's gui? Anyone care to explain and what should I do with my code?

```
URL url = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\plugins\\"+plugins).toURI().toURL();
URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};

ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
Class cls = cl.loadClass(mainclass);
Object plugs = cls.newInstance();
System.out.println("EXECUTING PLUGIN...");
Method meths = plugs.getClass().getMethod("getClassControl", JPanel.class);
meths.invoke(plugs, jPanel1);
System.out.println(plugins+" PLUGIN LOADED...");
```

This code is inside the parent app which is a jframe with a jpanel.
What the involked method does is it passes the jpanel object to the class and the class adds a jbutton that has an action to display the child jframe.

whenever I try to close the child jframe, the whole process is terminated. I also tried changing the close operation of the child jframe to dispose yet it yields the same result.

Comment: Probably you have something like `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)` in code for your child frame.

Comment: oh my goodness! I forgot the very basic of the behavior itself! thank you!, please propose as answer so I can mark it solved. I need to be more vigilant about these again..

Comment: You may need to address @SergiyMedvynskyy directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need to change

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
```

to

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE)
```

Comment: I prefer dispose on close tho its a case to case scenario. The important thing is it doesn't close down the whole application.